# Change the value depending on what has been specified

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using php and mysql...

A seller can sell a product. At the moment, they specify the quantity they wish to sell and the price they wish to sell the product at by filling in the form. This then gets saved in a DB...

However, I wish to modifiy this now so that...  The form looks something like this...

```
Product Name - Drop down box
Quantity - number specified by the user ... gets saved as a double
Price -  number specified by user.. saved as a double. 
Price per unit -- IMPLEMENT THIS SO THAT IT CHANGES ACCORDING TO WHAT the user types as the price and quantity...
```

So I wish to add the extra price per unit field... That gets automatically updated(calculated according to Price/quantity) according to the user input.

How would I be able to do something like this? Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks.

Comment: What is the calculation for that field?  What is its purpose?  Are you storing it, or just displaying it to the user?  If it's just for display purposes and doesn't need to be stored then it doesn't really need to be a "field" in the strictest sense, you could just use JavaScript to perform the calculation and update the display any time the other input fields change.

Comment: @David the calculation is the price/quantity that the user specifies on the form. It is used to work out the price per unit. I wish to do both store and display it.. So once the user is happy with the info filled in when they submit the form it will save the price, quantity and price per kg....

so what is the best action to take?? As i want the field to be calculated automatically as the user changes values and also then store that value once the form is submitted.. Thanks.

Comment: In that case (assuming the user shouldn't be able to edit it, since it's a calculated field) you should take both approaches in Amit's answer below.  Calculate it client-side to display to the user (but don't bother submitting it as part of the form, since the values needed to calculate it are already being submitted).  Then calculate it again server-side when writing the record to the database.  That way the user can't tamper with the field.

Comment: @David yes that is correct the user should be able to edit it.. Ahh I see thanks david I will give Amit approach a go.. Do I not need to use JQuery or JavaScript or anything like that to do it? Or can I use PHP?? As I do not know JavaScript or JQuery :(

Comment: For web development in general I would suggest learning some JavaScript.  If you need to perform the calculation in PHP, then that means that the page will need to post back to the server any time it needs to re-calculate.  If you intend to re-calculate any time either of the other two fields changes then you'll be reloading the page any time those fields change.  That would be a pretty awful user experience.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree with you there hence, I need to just learn a bit of JS... Is there anything in particular you would say I need to look up for something like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it at client side, then add onblur event on quantity and price input box and set the value of Price per Unit as Price/Quantity

If you want to do it in your query, then while inserting the record, calculate Price/Quantity and specify the value in your insert query

**UPDATE**

Please find sample HTML file with client side calculation at below link

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69417269/test.html

Comment: Hi Amit. Thanks for your reply. I will google what onblur is as I haven't used this before. And like I said to david I wanted to ideally, set the price per unit so that the user can not change the value since it is atomically calculated. Then use the value displayed to store into the DB. I also need the value to be only 2 decimal points.. i.e. price per unit has to be the format... £1.99 and not £1.989.. Is there any changes I will need to do for this??

Thanks

Comment: Will give you an example soon. Meanwhile google for onblur and javascriot mathematical operations. These all you need

Comment: Thanks Amit I shall google some right now... I am not very familiar with JS yet however, I do understand parts of the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample file, its not perfect, but it will get you going

Comment: Hi amit Yes that is exactly what I need and aim on doing... To view the source code I right click and view source right?

Comment: Thanks that works... I understand a little bit more about JS now as I have done a bit of Java in the past... I shall use the value on the priceperunit textbox and store that as a POST variable and then add that to the DB I think that should hopefully work.... Once again Thank you:)